# 110V AC to 3V AC for harmonic analysis

Tags: adc, signal

Looking for some general guidance on stepping down 110V Ac source for A/D conversion.
I am interested in capturing some of the harmonics in the source for analysis. My worry about using a step down transformer is hysteresis/ core saturation causing interference.
My requirement is to faithfully reproduce the incoming 110V AC signal at about 3V AC since my microcontroller analog input can only tolerate 3V.
Thanks

Comment: You could use a resistor divider. Keep the microcontroller cicuitry (which will be connected directly to the mains) isolated from the rest of the world by using optoisolators and an insulated case. Make sure the resistors have a sufficient voltage rating with a good safety factor. **I am not an electrical engineer.**

Comment: I agree the resistor divider is a reasonable approach.     You can make this much safer and simplier if your micro is battery operated and has no electrical connection to the AC mains (except at the resistor divider)

Comment: @KyleB Would it be prudent to add TVS diodes on the divided voltage side, or is 3 V too low for them to be workable, like the soft knee of Zener diodes at the lower end of their range?

Comment: Wirewound resistors are the best choice for noise, followed by metal film, metal oxide, carbon film, and lastly, carbon composition. However, wirewound resistors are not readily available in large resistance values

Comment: Diodes will add some capacitance.   Whether that matters will depend again on your frequencies of interest

Comment: Diode will also introduce leakage current that will throw off your measurement, especially at higher ambients

Comment: @JonRB That's a great point.     One more addition - OP if you are looking for absolute amplitude information (i.e. you wanna know '1V is really 1V'), you will have to take the ADC input impedance into account.   The ADC impedance is a resistance in parallel with the lower resistor in the voltage divider.    It may (probably) will be a negligible contributor, but don't assume it until you mathematically prove it to be.

Comment: Maybe put the fragile components (that could be most of them, including the fuse) in sockets for easy replacement. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

If the constraint is "faithfully reproduce" then one of the 1st things you need to consider is to what harmonic. The more harmonics you capture the closer to the actual waveform the data you acquire will be. This means higher and higher ADC rates.

A good rule of thumb is the sampling rate needs to be at least 10x higher than the frequency of interest. This is related to Nyquist sampling theorem but remember you do not have a perfectly band-limited signal and Nyquist never stated to use twice the sampling frequency in such situations ;).

10x will mean you can reconstruct the highest frequency of interest with a gain of 0.99 and a phase of 5.7 degrees. The closer your sampling frequency is to the frequency of interest, the further the quality to degrade until eventually you will hit aspects of Nyquist sampling theorem

How to measure? An isolated voltage divider would be the best option.

A resistor chain feeding an SAR would be the simplest but you then need isolated power and isolated signals. TI (and analog) have some nice digital isolators with integrated isolated DCDC which are good for a a reasonable amount of mA

[image]

Comment: Would I be correct that using fairly non-inductive resistors in the voltage divider would be a good idea, or is the inductance of any old resistor negligible for this application?

Comment: Capacitance is more of a concern than inductance. the current flowing is tiny but the dv/dt is <insert waveform>. Strays are always something to consider though

Comment: Inductive or non inductive resistors would probably only make a difference if the frequencies of interest are very high.   Like 100khz or maybe even higher

Comment: This design is unipolar, so perhaps Vref/2 bias must be added. Then you lose impulse dynamic range and be exposed to clipping. A Nyquist BW input filter must be considered.  Depends what you want to measure.

Comment: good point on it being unipolar, I picked it straight of one of my DClink sensing circuits. This includes an anti-aliasing filter pre-ADC at around 160kHz.